# PHP, how to print new line strings

Tags: php

How can I make a new line in php, for ex

```
$message='Name and Surname:'.$name.'  '.'Birthday: '.$Birthdate.'  '.' Nationality: '.$Nationality;
```

Output:

```
Name and Surname:LULZIM    Birthday: 1987       Nationality: Macedonia
```

How i want is:

```
Name and Surname:LULZIM
Birthday: 1987 
Nationality: Macedonia
```

BTW this output comes like this in the email, bc I am sending all this data in email, I tried adding \n and 
 but didnt worked :S

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is  it HTML? Try `$message=nl2br($message)`

Answer (score 6):

"\n" will work. You have to use double quotes rather than single quotes. If you want new lines in html, you need to echo `<br />`, which you can do in either single or double quotes.

Comment: I suggest better using PHP_EOL constant rather than "\n" because \n doesn't work in most Windows servers. PHP_EOL always returns the correct line break and avoids a lot of headache if you ever moved to a Windows server.

Answer (score 3):

add `<br>`:

```
$message='Name and Surname:'.$name.'  '.'<br>Birthday: '.$Birthdate.'  '.' <br>Nationality: '.$Nationality;
```

Comment: @AdnanShammout Looks cooler for sure, but why the extra keystroke? lol `Precious nanoseconds`. Actually, `2` extra keystrokes and is only required if using `XHTML`.

Comment: Those two key strokes make you XHTML compliant. Which makes you cool, and renders faster in the browser. (I made the last part up.)

Comment: @ScottSaunders Must... resist... starting... war... over... HTML vs XHTML. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To create an actual new line, use "\n" in double quotes. (Or use PHP_EOL).

To create a new line in HTML, use "<br />". (This is not symantic HTML, many would argue to use <p></p> tags.

```
$message = 'Name and Surname: ' . $name . "\n<br />"
         . 'Birthday: ' . $Birthdate . "\n<br />"
         . 'Nationality: ' . $Nationality . "\n<br />";
```

You could also simplify the code by using:

```
$message="Name and Surname: $name<br />\nBirthday: $Birthday<br />\n Nationality: $Nationality<br />\n"
```